# Converting xlsm to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have this simple snippet which used to work well until today. It converts xlsm files into csv.

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('T:/DataDump/3.26.17.xlsm')
for sheet in workbook.sheets():
    with open('{}.csv'.format(sheet.name), 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(sheet.row_values(row) for row in range(sheet.nrows))

print ("CSV converted")
```

xlsm file:

```
Name      Date              Status
Python    12/15/2014        Manager
Pandas    10/17/2014        Senior
```

csv file:

```
Name      Date              Status

Python    12/15/2014        Manager

Pandas    10/17/2014        Senior
```

This snippet is providing me with the csv but with double spaces between the rows. How can I fix this please?

Comment: I wonder if you are having issues with newlines.  You should be opening your file with the `newline=''` option: `with open('{}.csv'.format(sheet.name), 'w', newline='') as f:`

Comment: What does this show? `with open('{}.csv'.format(sheet.name), 'r') as f:print(repr(f.read()))`

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3,open `f` with the additional parameter `newline=''`

```
with open('{}.csv'.format(sheet.name), 'w', newline='') as f:
```

Comment: I wonder the same, but also under Python 2 he should have been using `'wb'` not `'w'` (although I think it may have made little difference on Windows).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski : you are right,he should use 'wb' not 'w' for python 2.